# MariaDB 10.1.12, console not responding when using -p

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Just out of the blue, I can no longer login to my local (Windows 7 64) DB (MariaDB 10.1.12) when I use a password for a given user. I also have another MySQL running in Vagrant (Ubuntu32 14.04), hence the `--port 3305` for the Windows one in these.

`$ mysql --version
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.12-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)`

All commands given in Windows / Git Bash:

`$ mysql --port 3305
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
The error message appears pretty much instantly, and is expected.

Then with a username that exists (not literally the one below):
`$ mysql --port 3305 -u my_username
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
Again, the error message appears immediately as expected.

**The question**:
In the same console, this command NEVER gets any response whatsoever. It's like MariaDB hangs/freezes (until Ctrl + C), even after an hour of waiting in the background. It seems to only happen when the `-p` parameter is set:

`$ mysql --port 3305 -u my_username -pcorrect_password`

`$ mysql --port 3305 -u my_username -p`

With the latter one, there should be a password prompt, but it also never appears. This config has worked before and nothing (that I know of) has changed? And MariaDB itself is working, since it does respond to the other commands. Why would a password prompt hang it?

Comment: Please try add another parameter ,e.g. --host localhost or --host 127.0.0.1

Comment: @mootmoot: I tried it now and the result was the same with both 127.0.0.1 and localhost. No response or messages. If I do just `mysql --port 3305 --host localhost`, it responds immediately with the expected `Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: So this confirm my suspicions, it is the db client connector behavior. I just post by answer.

Comment: If you type the password and Enter, does it work?  If so, then I would suggest that the Shell is doing something funny.

Answer (score 0):

Because Mariadb client also inherit a lot of MySQL code and behavior , so what is writing inside Mysql documentation : [Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html) may also happens to mariadb client.

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
>   way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
>   network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
>   **attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file**.
>   This occurs **even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
>   number**. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the
>   local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost

Apparently, mariadb client connect to 3305 even with the --port parameter. Since port 3305 is not running maraidb agent BUT the port is open, so mariadb client just wait until timeout (typical TCP/IP client tools behavior).    If 3305 is not open, mariadb client will give connection failure ASAP .